# Return a parameter for a function

Tags: python, function, parameters

How do I create three functions? At least one should have one parameter and one should return have at least one return value.

This is the question:

"Add at least three new functions to custom.py. At least one of them should take at
least one parameter, and at least one of them should have at least one return
value"

```
    enter code here# custom.py


def square(x):
    return x*x

def cube(x):
    return x*x*x

def circ(x):
    return x*x*x*x

def quad(x):
    return x*x*x*x*x

def sum():
    return square + cube + circ + quad





----

import custom # leave off the .py
def main():
 
    for num in range(25):
        print(num, end="\t")
        print(custom.square(num), end="\t")
        print(custom.cube(num), end="\t")
        print(custom.circ(num), end="\t")
        print(custom.quad(num))
        print(custom.sum)


    xmas= int(input("How many presents do you want? "))
    
    if xmas >10:
            print("You crazy!")
    elif xmas <10:
            print("That's not bad..")
            
    print("Done")
main()
 


-----
   
Output
    

0   0   0   0   0
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
1   1   1   1   1
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
2   4   8   16  32
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
3   9   27  81  243
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
4   16  64  256 1024
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
5   25  125 625 3125
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
6   36  216 1296    7776
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
7   49  343 2401    16807
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
8   64  512 4096    32768
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
9   81  729 6561    59049
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
10  100 1000    10000   100000
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
11  121 1331    14641   161051
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
12  144 1728    20736   248832
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
13  169 2197    28561   371293
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
14  196 2744    38416   537824
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
15  225 3375    50625   759375
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
16  256 4096    65536   1048576
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
17  289 4913    83521   1419857
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
18  324 5832    104976  1889568
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
19  361 6859    130321  2476099
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
20  400 8000    160000  3200000
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
21  441 9261    194481  4084101
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
22  484 10648   234256  5153632
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
23  529 12167   279841  6436343
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
24  576 13824   331776  7962624
<function sum at 0x7fc9f7aab430>
How many presents do you want? 10
Done
>>>
```

Comment: You are not calling `sum`. Add parentheses to actually execute it: `print(custom.sum())`

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum` function tries to sum functions rather than the results of functions.  (Also, naming it `sum` is bad because it overwrites the builtin `sum` function!)  It should be more like:

```
def sum_all_funcs(x):
    return square(x) + cube(x) + circ(x) + quad(x)
```

and then you should call it with a parameter:

```
print(custom.sum(num))
```